# Google AppEngine startup times

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've already read how to avoid slow ("cold") startup times on AppEngine, and implemented the solution [from the cookbook](http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/hot-handler) using 10 second polls, but it doesn't seem to help a lot.

I use the Python runtime, and have installed several handlers to handle my requests, none of them doing something particularly time consuming (mostly just a DB fetch).

Although the **Hot Handler** is active, I experience slow load times (up to 15 seconds or more per handler) and the log shows frequently the `This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time ...` message after the app was IDLE for a while.

This is very odd. Do I have to fetch each URL separately in the Hot Handler?

Comment: Please don't poll your app like that. It wastes resources, and as you've observed, it's ineffective to boot. Always on and warmup requests are the way to do this.

Comment: Well allways on is too expensive for this purpose, and warmup requests don't help when the instance shuts down after there is no traffic for some time. And running a cron every 1 minute to load an empty page doesn't really waste resources...

Comment: I'm sorry you think the offering is too expensive, but it is what it is. And yes, of course it wastes resources (and you're talking about every 10 seconds, even) - your app is occupying resources while idle that could be allocated more usefully elsewhere, and as you've already observed, it's ineffective too, since App Engine will spin up extra instances in response to demand. You're better off making your app more efficient so loading times are less of an issue, and paying for always on if it's really important. Please don't contribute to this tragedy of the commons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "appropriate" way of avoiding slow too many slow startup times is to use the ["always on" option](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Always_On). Of course, this is not a free option ($0.30 per day).

Comment: I know, but not ideal for a weekend project (9.30$ a month). Yes it's not much, but if you have many "hobby" apps it sums up...

Comment: enabling warmup requests is free and may also help.

Comment: Currently I've just set a 1 minute cron job onto an '/keepalive' route handler. Seems to work fine as well.

Comment: I just enabled warmup requests, but I still don't get whats wrong with this darn appengine thing. It just keeps spawning new instances instead of seriving requests (see [here](http://cl.ly/2y3O0B1b0W2H2R3A1C0V)). Just doesn't seem to work without a cron.